# View logs remotely in Websphere Liberty 8.5 running in production mode

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

When I use Websphere Liberty 8.5 in development mode, i.e. it's managed through Eclipse I can see all logs in Eclipse's console. When my application deployed on a Bluemix using Liberty Runtime I can connect to server's console using `cf logs <appName>` see explanation here: [Accessing Application Logs In Bluemix](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/10/29/accessing-application-logs-bluemix/) and view all logs remotely.

Can I do the same (view logs remotely in a terminal) in a Liberty Server deployed on private server?

Comment: you can do so using the /ibm/console which is the admin console.  you just have to be sure it is installed

Answer (score 1):

You are basically asking where to find the logs on WebSphere Liberty.

Liberty has a unified logging component that handles messages that are written by the product and provides First Failure Data Capture (FFDC) services. Additionally, the logging component captures messages that are written to *System.out*, *System.err*, *java.util.logging*, and *OSGi* logging (what you get when running `cf logs` on Bluemix).

The logging component can be controlled through the server configuration, and by default, the log directory is set to the *LOG_DIR* environment variable. The default *LOG_DIR* environment variable path is *WLP_OUTPUT_DIR/serverName/logs*.

Accessing those files from terminal you should get what you are asking for.

Please take a look at [Liberty - Logging and Trace](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html) to get more information.